# update MVC3 partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I am using MVC C# along with Jquery.
I have a partial view that's need to be updated every time the user modify some data from the view. The problem is that the partial view is not updated. How can update the partial view?

jquery code from the partial view (WorkReport)

```
 $("#modify").click(function () {
    var duration = $("#newDuration").val();
    var date_param = $("#dateParam").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ModifyDuration", "ViewWork")',
        type: 'post',
        data: { newDuration: duration, id: psm_id, date: date_param },
        dataType: 'text',
        traditional: true,
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#workList").html(data).trigger('create');
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult GetWorkList(string date)
    {
        model.workList = workList;
        return PartialView("WorkReport", model);

    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ModifyDuration(string newDuration, string id, string date)
    {
        DataOperation dataOperation = new DataOperation();
        dataOperation.UpdateWorkDuration(newDuration, id);
        return RedirectToAction("GetWorkList", new
        {
            date = date
        });
    }
```

Comment: You haven't actually posted a question, nor attempted to describe what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, what's the  question?

Comment: What's the question, dude ?

Comment: Where are you creating model and workList? Could it be that you are always loading the same data?

Comment: I tried to update the partial view after the user make some data modification, but this updating is not working.

Comment: @ Lews Therin; after the modifications are done, the `Modifyduration` action returns the `GetWorkList` action. In the `GetWorkList` action the model is created and passed to the partial view `WorkReport`. Then the partial view `WorkReport` is populated and rendered, but I get an error message `Error loading page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use [this](http://msprogrammer.serviciipeweb.ro/2011/12/05/jquery-ajax-request-and-mvcdetailed/) but please sure that select correctly page.or use load

```
$("#modify").load('@Url.Action("ModifyDuration", "ViewWork")');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had much more success loading Partials in JQuery using:

```
$("#modify").click(function () {
    $("#workList").load('/ViewWork/ModifyDuration');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard coding path (link) is a bad idea, so always use `@Url.Action()` method. Your code should be

```
$("#modify").click(function () {
    $("#workList").load('@Url.Action("ModifyDuration", "ViewWork")');
}
```